# How to upload package to my private YUM repository on Suse

Tags: yum, rpm, repository, suse, zypper

I have created a private repository and populated it with RPMs. I can query and install via the zypper package from remote Suse boxes which is great.

What is the neatest way to upload new packages to this private repository to keep it up to date?

Is it to rebuild the RPM (if it doesnt exist already) on the source box and then ftp the rpm to the Repository and then refresh the repo?

I figured there might be a tool or Yum, Yast, Zypper cmd that does these three steps.